# Mongodb $in operator performance impact when input array sorted or unsorted

Tags: mongodb, indexing, time-complexity

I have a collection with 50 million+ documents of unique mobile numbers in my `mongodb`.
There is `find` query on indexed field `mobile` using `$in` operator. Input array size range may vary from 1 to 5000.
As per mongodb doc indexing using `B+Tree` structure. Complexity of this is `Nlog(M)`, where M is number of indexed key and N is size of input array(`unsorted`).
now the question is If I am sorting the input array N (`sorted`) and then searching in db,
is there any option to optimise number of comparisons by sorting input array?

Number of comparisons for each element in input array-

```
  1st element=>(1*log(M))
  2nd element=>(1*log(M - IndexOf last searched element))
  3rd element=>(1*log(M - IndexOf last searched element))
  .....
  Nth element=>(1*log(M - IndexOf last searched element))
```

Or

Internally mongodb does like this only?

Minimising number of comparison as above does not impact on searching time?

It may create overhead for search which will increase search time?